# Apply Itô's Lemma to $\left| X_t\right|^2$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

We start with the stochastic differential equation
$$\mathrm{d}X_t=\lambda X_t\mathrm{d}t + \sigma X_t \mathrm{d}W_t,$$
where $\lambda,\sigma\in\mathbb{C}$.

I would like to apply Itô formula to obtain an equation for $\mathrm{d}\left|X_t\right|^2.$

Here's my attempt (using the fact that $|X_t|^2 = \mbox{Re}(X_t)^2+\mbox{Im}(X_t)^2$):
$$\mathrm{d}\left|X_t\right|^2=2\lambda X_t \Big(\mbox{Re}(X_t)+\mbox{Im}(X_t)\Big)\mathrm{d}t + |\sigma|^2\left|X_t\right|^2\mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}M_t,$$
where $\mathrm{d}M_t$ is the martingale term.

However, the notes I'm looking at say that we get
$$\mathrm{d}\left|X_t\right|^2=(2\mbox{Re}(\lambda)+|\sigma|^2)\left |X_t\right|^2\mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}M_t.$$

How did they get that, and how does the real part of $\lambda$ come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we treat $X$ as an $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued process, Itô's lemma says the relevant drift term is given by $\nabla f(X_t) \cdot \lambda X_t dt$.

You're right that $\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}\nabla f(X_t) = (2 \Re(X_t), 2 \Im(X_t))$.  But then $$\lambda X_t = (\Re(\lambda) \Re(X_t) - \Im(\lambda) \Im(X_t), \Re(\lambda) \Im(X_t) + \Im(\lambda) \Re(X_t)).$$  When you dot these, you find that the $\Im(\lambda)$ terms cancel and leave you with $$2 \Re(\lambda)(\Re(X_t)^2 + \Im(X_t)^2) = 2 \Re(\lambda) |X_t|^2.$$

Comment: I've tried dotting them, but I get $2\Big(\mbox{Re}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)^2-\mbox{Im}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)\mbox{Im}(X_t)-\mbox{Re}(\lambda)\mbox{Im}(X_t)^2-\mbox{Im}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)\mbox{Im}(X_t), \mbox{Re}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)\mbox{Im}(X_t)-\mbox{Im}(\lambda)\mbox{Im}(X_t)^2+\mbox{Re}(\lambda)\mbox{Im}(X_t)\mbox{Re}(X_t)+\mbox{Im}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)^2\Big)$

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt: How do you figure?  We are identifying $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and taking the dot product there, so the result of the dot product is a real number, not a complex number or vector.

Comment: In that case, I get $2\Big(\mbox{Re}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)^2-\mbox{Im}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)\mbox{Im}(X_t)+\mbox{Re}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)\mbox{Im}(X_t)+\mbox{Im}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)^2+\mbox{Re}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)\mbox{Im}(X_t)-\mbox{Im}(\lambda)\mbox{Im}(X_t)^2+\mbox{Re}(\lambda)\mbox{Im}(X_t)^2+\mbox{Im}(\lambda)\mbox{Re}(X_t)\mbox{Im}(X_t)\Big)$, which has an extra two terms with respect to what you got

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt: Dot product $(x,y) \cdot (u,v) = xu+yv$.  Your $\Re(\lambda) \Re(X_t) \Im(X_t)$ and $\Im(\lambda) \Re(X_t)^2$ terms should not appear.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks, I'll award the bounty this evening (i.e. when MSE lets me)